# dragula.js: unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, jquery, dragula

I am using dragula js to use drag and drop in mobile devices and suddenly ran into a problem where I am getting the following error.

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive. See

and the error hits the following function

```
function drag (e) {
    if (!_mirror) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    //other code
  }
```

what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the breaking upgrades to chrome 56  to improve the performance in scrolling,
Please check here

https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/468

You can define `touch-action: none` to the drag handle  to resolve the issue.

Seems to be a problem with bindings for the pointer events.

> My issue was solved by adding touch-action: none to the drag handle.

Comment: where can I find drag handle function?

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh check this https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#optionsmoves